# Error while displaying data from SQL VB 6

Tags: sql, vb6

I try to show several data in my table, I used **INNER JOIN** to display the data..
here's my code to display those data (works in SQLYog)

```
SELECT mahasiswa.NPM, mahasiswa.NamaMhs, mahasiswa.Jurusan, 
    mahasiswa.grup,mahasiswa.ta, bayar_lab.persen, bayar_dpp.persen
FROM bayar_dpp INNER JOIN bayar_lab ON bayar_dpp.NPM = bayar_lab.NPM 
INNER JOIN mahasiswa ON bayar_lab.NPM = mahasiswa.NPM 
ORDER BY mahasiswa.NPM
```

And here's my code on VB6 that will show these data on a VSFlexGrid
NOTE: "TampilGrid" function is to execute the Query I made

```
 Private Sub TampilGrid(ByVal SQLnya As String)
    Grid.Rows = 1

    Call AksesRS(SQLnya)
    While Not rs.EOF
        Grid.Rows = Grid.Rows + 1

        Grid.TextMatrix(Grid.Rows - 1, 0) = rs.Fields(0)
        Grid.TextMatrix(Grid.Rows - 1, 1) = rs.Fields(1)
        Grid.TextMatrix(Grid.Rows - 1, 2) = rs.Fields(2)
        Grid.TextMatrix(Grid.Rows - 1, 3) = rs.Fields(3)
        Grid.TextMatrix(Grid.Rows - 1, 4) = rs.Fields(4)

        lb_persendpp.Caption = Val(rs.Fields(5))
        lb_persenlab.Caption = Val(rs.Fields(6))
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End Sub
```

But an error occurred.. It shows

> "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal", especially in rs.Fields(3) but the rs.Fields(0)
>   until rs.Fields(2) not error

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What is the line on which the error occurs? Do a `debug.print rs.Fields.Count` before the loop to see how many fields are in recordset.

Comment: at `Grid.TextMatrix(Grid.Rows - 1, 3) = rs.Fields(3)` sir..

Comment: Note: (1) Instead of adding rows in your loop; set count of your recordset to it before loop - (2) Also check `rs.BOF` in while - (3) Before loop use `rs.MoveFirst` ;).

Comment: example please... I'm still a newbie...

Comment: If you do a msgbox `rs.Fields.Count`, do you get a value >= 4? If yes, maybe you should consider deleting the part `rs.Fields(3)` and re-type it instead of copy/paste. Edit your question to show what `AksesRS` function looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try using best practices,

1. If possible use filed names rather than field index i.e. `rs("empName")`.
2. Avoid Grid.Rows = Grid.Rows + 1 inside loop.
3. Check for db null values before assigning to the controls or variables.

Try below code.

```
Dim index as Integer
Grid.Rows = rs.RecordCount
index = 1
While Not rs.EOF
    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(0)) Then Grid.TextMatrix(index, 0) = rs.Fields(0)
    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(1)) Then Grid.TextMatrix(index, 1) = rs.Fields(1)
    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(2)) Then Grid.TextMatrix(index, 2) = rs.Fields(2)
    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(3)) Then Grid.TextMatrix(index, 3) = rs.Fields(3)
    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(4)) Then Grid.TextMatrix(index, 4) = rs.Fields(4)

    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(5)) Then lb_persendpp.Caption = Val(rs.Fields(5))
    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(6)) Then lb_persenlab.Caption = Val(rs.Fields(6))
    index = index + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: alternatively, you can avoid the if condition by simply concatenating empty string with the result. rs.Fields(0) & ""

Comment: You will need to change the Grid.Rows -1 to be a counter which will be incremented in the loop, otherwise you will keep updating the same row.